# MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect (client.close and client.connect issue)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

(node:21140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect

I think it is an error relating to repetition of client.connect and client.close in each function of CRUD operation as shown in code below

//I think there is no issue with cluster uri so I didn't post that since it connects fine

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const uri = "mongodb+srv://username:pasword@some cluster"; 
//I think there is no issue with cluster uri so I didn't post that since it connects fine


const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });



async function AddnewService(service) {
    await client.connect()
    const database = client.db("twitch")
   const usr = await database.collection("recipes").find({ Title: service.Title }).toArray()
    if (usr.length >= 1) {
        await client.close()
        return { message: "Title already in use" }
    }
    else {
        const result = await database.collection("recipes").insertOne(service)
        await client.close()
        return { message: "Service Added to Database" }
    }
}

async function FetchAllserviceSearch(service) {
    await client.connect()
    const database = client.db("twitch")
    let recipesCursor = await database.collection("recipes").find({})
    while (await recipesCursor.hasNext()) {                       //make sure to put await on cursor .hasnext()
        let recipe = await recipesCursor.next()
        console.log(recipe)
    }
    await client.close()

    return { message: "User Added to Database" }
}


module.exports = {
    AddnewService,
    FetchAllserviceSearch
}
```

I tried allot to make that client.connect and client.close be called only once but there have always be a new error caused by it.
I cannot eliminate module.export cause I need them for usage in other file.

So I need a little help to make it work out some how without that needless repetition as mongodbAtlas causes issues with that.

Comment: What happens when you move following line `const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });` inside of function instead of keeping at global le level? can you check that and let me know?

Comment: @Sohan  Hi, idk if that is how it was supposed to be but I think it is not giving that repetition of connection on and off error .  I tried a few times and I didn't get that error yet.. is there a draw back to it or is that the right way to do it ?

Comment: Check the answer below, you might need to do some twekas from below answer as per your need. Also if you are using express, you can do that at global express app initialisation

Comment: Also i would suggest going at modular progarmming instead of keeping these  kind on functions in one class.

Comment: @Sohan I will research on that . Am still new to Mongo Atlas and other cloud platform related things  so didn't knew many approaches to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't close your DB connection, you're in race condition, when two requests come one will close other will open.

```
client.close(); -----> remove
```

Use the same db connection for all the requests.

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://username:pasword@cluster0.ik1pu.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

let con;

async function connect(service) {
   if (con) return con; // return connection if already conncted
   const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
   con = client.connect()
   return con;
}


async function AddnewService(service) {
    const client = await connect();
    const database = client.db("twitch")
    const usr = await database.collection("recipes").find({ Title: service.Title }).toArray()
    if (usr.length >= 1) {
        // await client.close(); -----> remove
        return { message: "Title already in use" }
    }
    else {
        const result = await database.collection("recipes").insertOne(service)
        return { message: "Service Added to Database" }
    }
}

async function FetchAllserviceSearch(service) {
    const client = await connect();
    const database = client.db("twitch")
    let recipesCursor = await database.collection("recipes").find({})
    while (await recipesCursor.hasNext()) {                       //make sure to put await on cursor .hasnext()
        let recipe = await recipesCursor.next()
        console.log(recipe)
    }
    // await client.close(); -----> remove
    return { message: "User Added to Database" }
}


module.exports = {
    AddnewService,
    FetchAllserviceSearch
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadUmarKhan what errors are you getting ?

Comment: Nono it was my bad..  I rechecked it again and again and it works amazing..  I mean even the speed of request had increased. Idk what happened But the way u taught me to connect increased speed of CRUD on Mongo ATlas and I am not getting those errors anymore. I will now apply this in the major part of the project am working on. Hope nothing goes wrong. Thanks :) I will try to understand how u made that connection work faster and without errors.

Comment: Do we never close client connection at all ?

Comment: @MuhammadUmarKhan When your application relies on a database to query data, you can avoid closing the connection. You can write a logic to close the connection before you exit your node application.

Comment: @MuhammadUmarKhan To speed up the process we are connecting to the database once and using the same connection, in that way we are saving time on connecting to the database every time.

Comment: Got it. that clarifies things.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to close the client in a request handler, but your client is global.

If you want to have a global client, do not close it in request handlers.

If you want to close the client in request handlers, create the client in the handler of the same request.

Create a Connection class to manage the apps database connection.
MongoClient does not provide a singleton connection pool so you don't want to call `MongoClient.connect()` repeatedly in your app. A singleton class to wrap the mongo client works for most apps I've seen.

```
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

    class Connection {
    
        static async open() {
            if (this.db) return this.db
            this.db = await MongoClient.connect(this.url, this.options)
            return this.db
        }
    
    }
    
    Connection.db = null
    Connection.url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test_db'
    Connection.options = {
        bufferMaxEntries:   0,
        reconnectTries:     5000,
        useNewUrlParser:    true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
    
    module.exports = { Connection }
```

Everywhere you `require('./Connection'`), the `Connection.connectToMongo()` method will be available, as will the Connection.db property if it has been initialised.

```
const { Connection } = require('../lib/Connection.js')

        async function AddnewService(service) {
        // This should go in the app/server setup, and waited for.
        await Connection.connectToMongo()
        const database = Connection.db("twitch")
       const usr = await database.collection("recipes").find({ Title: service.Title }).toArray()
        if (usr.length >= 1) {
           // await client.close()
            return { message: "Title already in use" }
        }
        else {
            const result = await database.collection("recipes").insertOne(service)
           // await client.close()
            return { message: "Service Added to Database" }
        }
    }
```

In express you can do something like this,

```
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
    let mongoClient = null;
    MongoClient.connect(config.mongoURL, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true},function (err, client) {
        if(err) {
          console.log('Mongo connection error');
        } else {
          console.log('Connected to mongo DB');
          mongoClient = client;
        }
    })
let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    req.db = mongoClient.db('customer_support');
    next();
});
```

And use in your request handles like this,

```
    router.post('/hello',async (req,res,next)=>{
    let uname = req.body.username;
    let userDetails = await AddnewService(req.db,uname) // change signature of this method
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.data = userDetails;
    next();
});
```

Comment: Got it.. this clarified things even more. thanks allot for helping out.  And Ya am using express.js

Comment: So do you want to configure at global level  in express?

Comment: Ya what I usually do in offline MongoDB (Not MongoAtlas)   that I create connection once globally and then later simply use function calls later onwards. I tried to mimic that method in MongoAtlas but things went south.

Comment: I have updated answer for using mongo client at global level in express

Comment: Thanks I till check it out and try to understand